# My motorcycle is making whirrng grinding noise

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, gixxer-155

My Suzuki Gixxer 155 is making a weird grinding whirring noise. The noise is there when the clutch is open. As soon as I pull the clutch the noise goes away and there is no noise in neutral too or while idling. Also, I think the grinding noise increase when I put 5th gear to lower gear, say 2nd or 1st gear. but when I stop my motorcycle and start from 1st gear, less grinding whirring noise. I know when you put 5th gear to first gear there will be noise, but mine seems to be grinding and whirring. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!